# How can I embed a Tweet?

Tags: html, twitter, embed

How can I embed tweets inside of HTML? Let's say I want to embed this tweet: https://twitter.com/Rntk____/status/1245167253630251008

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click the `▼` button on your tweet
2. Then, click the button that says `</> Embed tweet`
3. All you need to do now is copy the code.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="en" dir="ltr"> A 101-year-old man, who survived the Spanish flu pandemic &amp; World War II has now added <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/COVID%E3%83%BC19?src=hash&amp;ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">#COVIDー19</a> to the list, after being discharged from hospital in Rimini.<br><br>Wow!  <a href="https://twitter.com/Rntk____/status/1245167253630251008">pic.twitter.com/7OtN2Sv3lp</a></p>&mdash; World Updates (@Rntk____) <a href="https://twitter.com/Rntk____/status/1245167253630251008?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">April 1, 2020</a></blockquote> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Here's what it looks like in an HTML page: 
[image: Embedded Tweet in HTML]

Answer (score 0):

Go to [publish.twitter.com](https://publish.twitter.com)

Paste in the Tweet URL and hit Enter.

Then you can either customize via the link above the Tweet, or simply copy the code.

The alternative option is to use [Twitter's oembed API endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-oembed) to get the same information back via backend code, and embed into your site.